# How do i format Ckeditor editor elements in the html after saving them into a database(flask)?

Tags: flask, ckeditor

I'm using Ckeditor for my web application, but after saving into the database i tried to display what was written but it didn't get the same format (for example non code highligth and so on)which i saw when editing on CKeditor. I try to find somethingh but just can't figure out. can you help me thank you.

Comment: HTML is not making it into the database or it is not making it into the template you are viewing it on? If its in the db but not in the template I think you need to escape the html.

Comment: @ThePyGuy it is not making it into the template i can save it into the database but in the template i only see the raw html with all the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the HTML data through the jinja safe filter. It is to prevent CSRF attacks you know this is safe html to execute so in your template.

`{{ thedata|safe }}`

Comment: thank you!(i also forget to do a reference to a css file)